# How to limit the number the dot charaters

Tags: ruby, regex

I need a regular expression to avoid a user from writing the following:

> .........  y that the validation passes. That at most he writes 2 points

I thought of doing it with:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]{6,30}$/
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.{0,2}_-]{6,30}$/
```

but they are not working. What should I do to verify this string?

Comment: Do you have to do the whole validation with one regex?

Comment: No is optional. You tell me that I do it for code with some method that verifies the amount of points. I am not used to use regular expressiones. I come the C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your second regular expression can be broken out into two parts:

```
/^[.]{0,2}[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{6,30}$/
```

Which says, essentially, a matching line may begin with 0, 1, or 2 "dots" followed by between 6 and 30 letters, numbers, _ or - characters.